# Will a thread be restarted again if it encounters the thread_create statement again?

Tags: pthreads

I am using pthreads and i have this doubt whether a thread will be restarted again if it encounters the same create statement that created  it?

Comment: No. Every time you encounter pthread_create, you create a **new** thread. A thread is never restarted. But you can start a new thread with the same code.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Lets say i have a thread t1. What happens if encounters the create statement, pthread_create(&t1,NULL,func,NULL). How can a new thread be created if i have a unique thread identifier , say the name  t1?

Comment: @alex That'll create *another* thread and run the `func` thread function, independent of previous thread. If you use the same thread id (`t1`) then it'll still create another thread - just that you'll lose the access to previous thread id (so you can't *join* for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will a thread be restarted again if it encounters the thread_create statement again?

It'll create a new thread regardless of whether it's called by thread that itself was created via `pthread_create`.

> Lets say i have a thread t1. What happens if encounters the create statement, pthread_create(&t1,NULL,func,NULL). How can a new thread be created if i have a unique thread identifier , say the name t1?

In this case, you are still creating new thread but just reusing/overwriting the previous thread identifier `t1`. Which means you can only call [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) on the second you created but lose the ability to `pthread_join`, change attributes of the first thread, and so on on the first thread. Note that this is still valid. But if this is your use-case, you are probably better off creating *detached* threads (either by setting the attribute before creating the first thread or by calling [`pthread_detach`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) from the thread function). A detached thread can't be *joined* and whose resources are freed when the thread exits (i.e., either by calling `pthread_exit` or by returning from the thread function).

Comment: Also i have another question if you don't mind. How to pass NULL value as a parameter to a thread? It says unable to convert from (void*)(*)() to (void*)(*)(void*). P.S. I am new to threads and can't seem to figure it out

Comment: `pthread_create(&t1,NULL,func,NULL);` is how you'd pass NULL argument to the thread function. Might help if you update the question with the exact code that produces that warning.